# Should Python constructors start services or only initialize variables?

Tags: python, oop

I am creating a Python class which should manage a Docker service via the Python Docker SDK.

Should I start the Docker container in the constructor of my class or is it better to create a method `start()` which has to be manually called afterwards (and in the constructor only initialize the class attributes)?

For C++ there is the RAII idiom where the connection would be set up in the constructor, for Java I've always heard that the constructor should be light-weight and not do any calculations or other "heavy" stuff.

What is the best way in Python?

Comment: This is primarily opinion based, but I'd say RAII does not apply to languages which do not have C++ way of cleaning up in destructors. Also, it is nice to be able to construct the object beforehand, do that it can be passed to another function to be `start`ed at a later time.

Comment: I've heard it's more idiomatic to have `connect`, `open`, `start`, ... methods in python rather than a constructor that automagically acquires resources. Similarly with destructors. Another idea is to implement a `contextmanager`.

Answer (score -1):

First of all I would like to highlight use of incorrect terminology here. Constructor and Initializer are two different things in Python. Constructors are implemented under the hood with `__new__` method and it controls the creation of the object of a class. Initializer use `__init__`  method and controls the initlialization of the object after it has been created.

In almost all cases constructors are called implicitly using base class's implementation of `__new__` and you rarely have a need to override it, however with initializer it is the exact opposite, because you would want to customize the object initialization after it has been created.

Now coming to your question, it depends on how you want to control your application, I do not see any problem if you start the container in the initliazer of the class i.e. inside `__init__`. What this would do is as soon as the object is created it will fire up the docker container as well.

However if you want to be more explicit about it and want to have separate instance methods for  `start` and `stop`, even that would not be a problem, its just that now you need to explicitly call the `start` method after the object has been created.

Comment: This "`__init__` isn't a constructor" thing needs to die. Allocating the instance isn't part of the job of construction. A constructor's job is initialization. `__init__` is a constructor, and `__new__` is a weird combination allocator/second constructor thing they had to retrofit into the language when they realized `__init__` wasn't going to cut it after type/class unification.

Comment: `__init__` is not constructor, `__new__` is !!, also `__new__` isn't second constructor it is the only constructor, try overriding `__new__` and messing its implementation and you will see object creation fails, no matter even if you have `__init__` implemented correctly. Finally before you downvote please understand the context properly!!

Comment: I don't think you know what a constructor *is*. Go look at Java, or Javascript, or C++, or C#, or Scala, or almost any other language with constructors, and you'll find they work like `__init__`. There are languages whose constructors work like `__new__`, but they're a lot less common.

Comment: I know what a constructor is and how it works, but we are talking about python here and not any other language and in python the constructor and initializer are two different things. So I believe you didn't know how python's object creation works and saying `__init__` is _constructor_ in python is very naive.